# How to convert a readfile to a read URL?

Tags: java, boggle

I'm trying to implement a URL connection that has a list of words my program reads, but currently can't find a solution. My code at the moment reads from a .txt file but I need it to read a list from a URL

I've tried:

```
URL url = new URL("my url ");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);


public static List<String> readFileInList(String myFileName) 
 { 
   List<String> lines = Collections.emptyList(); 
   try
   { 
     lines = 
      Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
   } 

   catch (IOException e) 
   { 

     e.printStackTrace(); 
   } 
   return lines; 
 } 
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException

   List l = readFileInList("my file"); 
   char board[][] = {
             {'X','A','G','L','K'},
             {'Y','U','P','T','K'},
             {'Z','Y','N','X','M'},
             {'Q','G','E','E','B'},
             {'R','O','A','P','Q'}};
   System.out.println("");
   Search(board);
```

Comment: “…but that's not what I need.” Please edit your question and tell us what you *do* need.

Answer (score 0):

My small web scraping app for you:
[web scraping app](https://github.com/TheBestSoftInTheWorld/web-scraping)

The app get data from URL